# Django TIME_ZONE definition ignored by time.tzname

Tags: django, timezone, python-3.5, django-1.8

I need use Timezone in a Django app.
I defined in settings.py UTC timezone :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

I put the following code in a view :

```
import time
print(time.tzname)
```

But it displays me :

```
('Paris, Madrid')
```

Do you know how to define timezone in all the Django app ?

Comment: you should use django.utils.timezone for timezones in django

Comment: Ok define USE_TZ and TIME_ZONE is not enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your settings are fine. `time.tzname` just tells you what Python thinks the local system time zone is, it has nothing to do with your Django settings.

If you use [`django.utils.timezone.get_default_timezone_name()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.get_default_timezone_name) you should see UTC as you expect.